# Favicon: How do I make it show in browser?

Tags: html, favicon

Ok, I have tried the following:

- placed the favicon.ico (the .ico I made using a [favicon generator](http://www.favicon.cc/http://)) in the root directory
- used the following code in my header:

```html
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <title>Kerris Ganeson Illustration</title>
</head>
```

- I have tried variations of this code that I have found online including:

```html
<link rel=”icon” href=”favicon.ico” type=”image/x-icon”>
<link rel=”shortcut icon” href=”favicon.ico” type=”image/x-icon”>
```

- I have cleared all of my browsers cache each time I try a new method
- I have also run a few of those online favicon validators that tell me my favicon is indeed there.
- When I go to kerrisganeson.co.uk/favicon.ico I do not get an error, just a blank page

My website is www.kerrisganeson.co.uk

(As an extra point, the titles on my site do not seem to be working, has that got something to do with it? I thought maybe it was because I'm forwarding the URL but that could be another problem for another day! Also, there is just a blank space where the favicon should be, no little white page that normally shows when a site has no favicon.)

I am super new to this and think I must be doing something silly but I can't for the life of me figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ” should be ". The characters are different.

Comment: You don't have that code in the header now. Did you save your html-file to the right place?

Comment: Hi, do I not? I have just checked my html file and the code is there?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the frames that you (or your hosting) are using.

Although your page (http://69.195.124.161/~kerrisga/) has the icon set up correctly:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

the page that contains the frame (http://www.kerrisganeson.co.uk/) doesn't have the icon set up correctly:

```
<link href=" " rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
```

It is empty, and that's why you don't see any icon.

To fix the problem:

- Avoid the frameset if possible (frames are not supported in HTML5)
- Set up the icon in the page that contains the frameset

Comment: Thank you for that, I had an inkling it was something to do with the frameset, when you say 'Avoid the frameset if possible' I'm not too sure what you mean. What is a frame (sorry for the noob question!)

Comment: No problem. I think I'm going to have a hard time explaining it (please someone correct me if I'm wrong): `frameset` and `frame`s allow you to have multiple views on the same page (you'd be opening multiple files and displaying them in only one page). They were relatively common in the past, but the inconvenience of using them (not web accessible, difficult to index, difficult to maintain...) and the possibility of replicating their behavior by using other methods (div, CSS, AJAX) made them obsolete. In fact, they are no longer supported in the HTML5 standard, so they are not valid HTML5.

Comment: Your web page (btw, great illustrations) itself doesn't use frames; the one that "holds" it is the problematic one.

Comment: Ok, does that mean that if I set the url forwarding of my www.kerrisganeson.co.uk domain to 'URL Redirect' rather than 'URL Frame' could that fix this problem? The issue with that when I tried it before was that the domain stopped showing as kerrisganeson.co.uk but instead showed my temporary url which looked like this: http://69.195.124.161/~kerrisga/

Comment: Thank you by the way :D Also, when you say the icon is set up as empty, this is not what it looks like in my html file. it looks like this: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">

Comment: I don't know exactly how you have the domain redirection set up, but yes, it's in the settings for URL Redirect/URL frame. Are there more options apart from those two? Apart from that, the favicon that is displayed is the one from the "parent/frame page": what you have in your html page doesn't really matter while the real page is just a frame (see it as a tunnel to your page), and doesn't have a defined favicon.

Comment: Yep the options are URL Redirect
URL Frame
A (Address)
CNAME (Alias)
Txt Record
URL Redirect (301)
AAAA (IPv6)
NS Record
SRV Record

Comment: Sorry, a little easier to read: URL Redirect, URL Frame, A (Address), CNAME (Alias), Txt Record, URL Redirect (301), AAAA (IPv6), NS Record, SRV Record. And I currently have no access to that tunnel page right? How frustrating! Thanks so much for your help so far, you're making it much clearer!

Comment: That "tunnel page" is probably created by your hosting because you selected "URL Frame". You will have to play with the settings (maybe Address or CNAME, and specify http://69.195.124.161/~kerrisga/ as the target page)

Comment: Ok Alvaro, I'll have a play around now I know the bigger problem! Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<title>My title</title>
</head>
</html>
```

Should work fine. Make sure your favicon:
-exists (your favicon refers to the right URL)
-is a correct file format (try using an existing favicon, e.g. http://www.redditstatic.com/favicon.ico as a source to see if that solves your problem)